# strange ArgumentOutOfRangeException in NumericUpDown

Tags: c#, winforms

In my current project, I am using `NumericUpDowns` to display some values.
Everything's fine, but there's one line of code that throws an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`, which is the third one of the following:

```
verBox.SelectedIndex = (int)currentConfig.Version; //enum, casting to int
startIndexBox.Value = currentConfig.StartIndex + 1;
intervalBox.Value = currentConfig.Interval;
```

so verBox is a `ComboBox`, startIndexBox and intervalBox are `NumericUpDowns`.
When this code is executed, the fields of currentConfig have following values:

```
currentConfig.Version = 2
currentConfig.StartIndex = 0
currentConfig.Interval = 700
```

Now the strange thing is the exception (thrown in the third line of this code):
It says that the Value 2 is invalid, and that it should be between `Minimum` and `Maximum`.
First thing is, that the value is not 2, but 700.
And the second thing is, that intervalBox.Minimum is 0, and the Maximum is 10k.

Also, Visual Studio doesn't break at this exception, but the program ends with `Code -1073741819 (0xc0000005) 'Access violation'`. If I set all exceptions to be thrown in the debugging settings, it breaks and I can see that currentConfig.Interval is 700, and there is in fact no reason for this exception to be thrown.
Another strange thing I observed is, that if I surround the last line of this code with a try/catch, the same exception is thrown on the line above it.

Did someone experience anything like this before? Or any ideas on how to solve this?

Edit: If I set a breakpoint on the line that throws the exception, the exception is thrown anyways.

Comment: Try clean->rebuild->run.

Comment: Didn't solve the problem :/

Comment: A C# that bombs with an access violation almost always has a corrupted GC heap.  Which means that you cannot reason about reasonable behavior anymore.  The heap is corrupted, anything can happen.

Comment: @HansPassant so what can I do about it?

Comment: When visual studio do such things, I restart it, if this didn't solve the problem, I copy my project files (*.cs) to a new project. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I solved the problem now: Visual Studio marked the exception on the wrong line. The problem was, that startIndexBox.Value got an index which was indeed out of range, causing the exception to occur.

Answer (score 1):

Verify that `currentConfig` is not null by an `if` check. If it is not null, verify that the properties of `Version`, `StartiIndex` and `Interval` contain values which are expected and proper for the numeric controls.

Also verify that the numeric controls are valid and on the page and ready to accept values at the point you want to load them.

Comment: What I didn't include is, that I already verify whether currentConfig is null or not.

Comment: Also, as I wrote in my question, every value should be perfectly fine, and the controls should be able to load them without any problems.

Comment: @Chester "Every value should be perfectly fine?" :-)

Comment: @Chester TY, I have worked with those controls and it (at least for me) was the *one parameter off* situation which bizarrely couldn't be handled in a better way by the control. So with that in mind your sentence about it being in the debugger, yet one line above, was why I wrote the response to check values. Regardless, I am glad it was resolved.